# How to access key by value in a dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a dict that looks like the following:

```
d = {"employee": ['PER', 'ORG']}
```

I have a list of `tags ('PER', 'ORG',....)` that is extracted from the specific `entity list`.

```
for t in entities_with_tag: # it includes words with a tag such as: [PER(['Bill']), ORG(['Microsoft']), 
    f = t.tag # this extract only tag like: {'PER, ORG'}
    s =str(f)
    q.add(s)
```

Now I want if `{'PER, ORG'}` in `q`, and it matched with `d.values()`, it should give me the `keys` of `{'PER, ORG'}` which is `'employee'`. I try it this but does not work.

```
for x in q:
   if str(x) in str(d.values()):
       print(d.keys()) # this print all the keys of dict.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you should loop he dictionary instead of the tag list. You can check if the dictionary tags are in the list using sets.

```
d = {"employee": ['PER', 'ORG'],
    "located": ["ORG", "LOC"]}
q = ["PER", "ORG", "DOG", "CAT"]
qset = set(q)
for key, value in d.items():
    if set(value).issubset(qset):
        print (key)
```

Output:

```
employee
```

Comment: I have faced a new problem if we have `"employee": ["PER", "LOC"]`, and  `"Located": ["ORG", "LOC"]`. As the `"LOC"` is in both keys, it returns both keys, where I want exactly if both values are the same, not one value. How to fix this?

Comment: It should not return "Located" (and in fact don't) unless "LOC" is in your q.

Comment: unfortunately, it returns both keys, because I have the `"LOC"` in both. How to make it that both values should be the same not only one.

Comment: I don't understand. Right now both values have to be in q for the key to be returned. If this is not the expected behaviour, as I said, maybe it is because you have both "ORG" and "LOC" in your q list. So something have to be changed in the tag extraction process.

Comment: The dictionary tags are also in the `sentences`, and we map it to the dictionary. Now in the `dictionary` we have `"employee": ["PER", "LOC"]`, and `"Located": ["ORG", "LOC"]`. But my question is how to fix the dictionary if `both values` are matched with both values of `q`, then it should return the key, not only match with one values, as it does right now.

Comment: In fact it DOESN'T match with one value. Updated my answer so that you can try the code yourself.

Comment: Yes, I run your code, it works, but in my case, It prints both,

Answer (score 1):

You mean with... nothing?

```
for x in q:
   if str(x) in d.values():
       print(d.keys())
```

Comment: It does not print anything.

Comment: @Zia Ugh, strange, copy it again

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to switch keys and values in the dict and then access by key.

```
tags = ('PER', 'ORG')
data = dict((val, key) for key, val in d.items())
print(data[tags])
```

Just be careful to convert the lists in tuples, since lists are not hashable.

Another solution would be to extract both key and value in a loop. But that's absolutely NOT efficient at all.

```
for x in q:
    if str(x) in str(d.values()):
        for key, val in d.items():
            if val == x:
                print(key) # this print all the keys of dict.
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make two lists. One which contains the keys and one which contains the values. Then for the index of the required value in the list with values you can call the key from the list of keys.

```
    d = {"employee": ['PER', 'ORG']}

    key_list = list(d.keys()) 
    val_list = list(d.values()) 

    print(key_list[val_list.index(['PER','ORG'])
```

Refer: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-key-from-value-in-dictionary/